How can I resolve this OML4py proxy error?
For example, the apply function works with the pandas DataFrame but but OML dataframes don't support the apply method. I get this error
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'
How can I resolve this?
'''
%python
import oml
import pandas as pd

inp = [{'VAL_1':10, 'VAL_2':1}, {'VAL_1':11,'VAL_2':10}, {'VAL_1':12,'VAL_2':0}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
oml_df = oml.push(df)

# The apply function works with the pandas DataFrame:

%python

df['VAL_NEW'] = df.apply(lambda row, arg: row['VAL_1'] + row['VAL_2'] +100, axis=1, args=(100,))
print(df)

# But OML dataframes don't support the apply method:

%python

oml_df['VAL_NEW'] = oml_df.apply(lambda row, arg: row['VAL_1'] + row['VAL_2'] +100, axis=1, args=(100,))

# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'

'''

Again: please read the description of the ML tag. It has nothing to do with "machine learning".

OML4Py does not overload the apply method. The equivalent code can be achieved using the + and concat method.
%python

new_col = oml_df['VAL_1'] + oml_df['VAL_2'] + 100
oml_df = oml_df.concat({"VAL_NEW": new_col})
oml_df

 VAL_1  VAL_2  VAL_NEW
0     12      0      112
1     10      1      111
2     11     10      121

